# Windows API function CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials also returns an error of 31

Tags: c++, winapi

When I use the function **CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials** to display a windows security authentication dialog, the return result is always 31 and the dialog doesn't display.
What's wrong with the code below?

```
CREDUI_INFO credui;  
credui.pszCaptionText = "Enter Network Password";  
credui.pszMessageText = ("Enter your password to connect to: " + strDbPath).c_str();  
credui.cbSize = sizeof(credui);  
credui.hbmBanner = nullptr;  
ULONG authPackage = 0;  
LPVOID outCredBuffer = nullptr;  
ULONG outCredSize = 0;  
BOOL save = false;  
int result = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(&credui, 0, &authPackage, nullptr, 0, &outCredBuffer, &outCredSize, &save, 1);
```

Comment: That error is produced by a device driver.  Your machine appears to be in bad shape, perhaps something borken with the networking driver stack.  Try another machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

31 is `ERROR_GEN_FAILURE`.  If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375178.aspx), there is a comment that says:

> I'm not sure why but it seems that CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsA always return ERROR_GEN_FAILURE (0x1E). Only Unicode version works.

You are, in fact, calling the Ansi version of `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials()` (as evident by the fact that you are assigning `char*` data to the `CREDUI_INFO` struct).  Try calling the Unicode version instead.

Also, you are not assigning a value to the `credui.hwndParent` field, and you are not zeroing out `credui` before populating it, so the `hwndParent` has an indeterminate value.  You must specify a valid `HWND`.  If you don't have one, you can use `NULL`.

Also, you are assigning a `char*` pointer from a temporary `string` to `credui.pszMessageText`.  That `string` goes out of scope and gets destroyed   before `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials()` is called.  You need to use a local variable to hold the message text until `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials()` is done using it.

Try this:

```
std::wstring strDbPath = ...;
std::wstring strMsg = L"Enter your password to connect to: " + strDbPath;

CREDUI_INFOW credui = {};
credui.cbSize = sizeof(credui);  
credui.hwndParent = nullptr;
credui.pszMessageText = strMsg.c_str();
credui.pszCaptionText = L"Enter Network Password";
credui.hbmBanner = nullptr;

ULONG authPackage = 0;  
LPVOID outCredBuffer = nullptr;  
ULONG outCredSize = 0;  
BOOL save = false;  

int result = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(&credui, 0, &authPackage, nullptr, 0, &outCredBuffer, &outCredSize, &save, 1);
```

Comment: You're correct. Only the Unicode version of this function works. Got no idea why..